# Bootstrap section with min-height doesn't stretch

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap layout that has 100vh min-height sections. That works for the most part. If I have a lot of text, the section will stretch to fit the amount of text, like it should.

However, if I have some Bootstrap buttons in the section and the window is too narrow, the section does not stretch to fit. The buttons spill out. I'm not sure how to fix this.

```css
#hero {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  background: url(../img/xbg1.jpg) top center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  #hero {
    background-attachment: fixed;
  }
}

#hero:before {
  content: "";
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#hero .hero-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

#hero h1 {
  margin: 30px 0 10px 0;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 56px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #hero h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 36px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #hero h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
}

.sectionbutton {
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="hero">
    <div class="hero-container" style="background: #8A8175; background-image: url(img/certificatebg.jpg); background-size: 100%; padding-top: 75px;">
 <div class="row" style="width: 70%; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"><button type="button" class="btn sectionbutton">Section 1</button></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"><button type="button" class="btn sectionbutton">Section 2</button></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"><button type="button" class="btn sectionbutton">Section 3</button></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"><button type="button" class="btn sectionbutton">Section 4</button></div>

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"><button type="button" class="btn sectionbutton">Section 5</button></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"><button type="button" class="btn sectionbutton">Section 6</button></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"><button type="button" class="btn sectionbutton">Section 7</button></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"><button type="button" class="btn sectionbutton">Section 8</button></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"><button type="button" class="btn sectionbutton">Section 9</button></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"><button type="button" class="btn sectionbutton">Section 10</button></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"><button type="button" class="btn sectionbutton">Section 11</button></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"><button type="button" class="btn sectionbutton">Section 12</button></div>

</div>

<!-- #hero --></div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understant why if you're using bootstrap, you're positioning the .hero-container absolutely, theres really no need to.

Removing this enables the background to fill the space as I understand you want to do. I also suspect the min-height: 100vh was causing this problem too, viewport height is just that, it'll fill the viewport height nothing else.

```css
#hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  background: url(../img/xbg1.jpg) top center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  #hero {
    background-attachment: fixed;
  }
}

#hero:before {
  content: "";
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#hero .hero-container {
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

#hero h1 {
  margin: 30px 0 10px 0;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 56px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #hero h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 36px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #hero h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
}

.sectionbutton {
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="hero">
    <div class="hero-container" style="background: #8A8175; background-image: url(img/certificatebg.jpg); background-size: 100%; padding-top: 75px;">
 <div class="row" style="width: 70%; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"><button type="button" class="btn sectionbutton">Section 1</button></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"><button type="button" class="btn sectionbutton">Section 2</button></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"><button type="button" class="btn sectionbutton">Section 3</button></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"><button type="button" class="btn sectionbutton">Section 4</button></div>

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"><button type="button" class="btn sectionbutton">Section 5</button></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"><button type="button" class="btn sectionbutton">Section 6</button></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"><button type="button" class="btn sectionbutton">Section 7</button></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"><button type="button" class="btn sectionbutton">Section 8</button></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"><button type="button" class="btn sectionbutton">Section 9</button></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"><button type="button" class="btn sectionbutton">Section 10</button></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"><button type="button" class="btn sectionbutton">Section 11</button></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"><button type="button" class="btn sectionbutton">Section 12</button></div>

</div>

<!-- #hero --></div>

</section>
```